# How to make this search engine work with subsrt_count?

Tags: php, echo, search-engine, file-get-contents

So, i've been working on making a search engine without the use of a database. What it's supposed to do is find the word searched for in the webpage and automatically give it's link. Here's it's code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$searchInput = $_POST['search'];

   $inputPage1 = $_SESSION['pOneText'];
   $inputPage2 = isset($_SESSION['pTwoText']) ? $_SESSION['pTwoText'] : "";
   $inputPage3 = isset($_SESSION['pThreeText']) ? $_SESSION['pThreeText'] : ""; 

    $fUrl = file_get_contents("mDummyP.php");
    $sUrl = file_get_contents("sDummyP.php");
    $tUrl = file_get_contents("tDummyP.php");

    if (substr_count($fUrl, $searchInput) !== false) {
        echo "All results for <strong> $searchInput </strong> : <br>" ;
    } elseif (substr_count($sUrl, $searchInput) !== false) {
        echo "All results for <strong> $searchInput </strong> : <br>";
    } elseif (substr_count($tUrl, $searchInput) !== false) {
        echo "All results for <strong> $searchInput </strong> : <br>";
    } else {
        echo "No resulst for <strong> $searchInput </strong>! ";
    }

    ?>
```

However, it never checks if the word actually exists or not, it always returns "all results for". So, i was wondering if anyone knew why or had suggestions to improve it. Keep in mind that it will never be used professionally, it's just to test my abilities. Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMO, this will be a resource eater? correct me if i'm wrong but are you trying to crawl 100's of thousands of websites at every query ?

Comment: Nope, it's for my website, the engine will search the string just in my websites page and then report the exact link of it.

Comment: Is your website content static ?

Comment: i don't think so, no, it's fixed.

Comment: The current webpage i'm testing this on is a dummy page.

Comment: have you tried doing a foreach loop at the files? `foreach($files as $file){ fopen($File); }`

Comment: İ'll try doing so and shall let you know.

Comment: @KristianHareland "correct me if i'm wrong but are you trying to crawl 100's of thousands of websites at every query?" - what gave you this impression? It is just getting data from files on the local server using file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the php manual for [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

> Return Values
>
> This function returns an integer.

Thus it will ALWAYS go into this first if block:

```
if (substr_count($fUrl, $searchInput) !== false) {
```

because the return value of substr_count is only ever an integer and is NEVER going to be false - your code is checking for the exact value and type of `false`.

Furthermore, apart from the else block, all of the statements are just echo'ing the exact same string so you will not see any differentiation of output if execution did go into the if or elseif blocks. See below to get you on the right track:

```
$searchInput = 'some';

$fUrl = 'this is test file text';
$sUrl = 'this is some other text';
$tUrl = 'extra text';

if (substr_count($fUrl, $searchInput) !== 0) {
    echo "a";
} elseif (substr_count($sUrl, $searchInput) !== 0) {
    echo "b";
} elseif (substr_count($tUrl, $searchInput) !== 0) {
    echo "c";
} else {
    echo "No resulst for <strong> $searchInput </strong>! ";
}
```

Comment: So you what are you suggesting?

Comment: Edited my answer, please take a look again and if this helps you please upvote and consider marking the tick as the accepted answer to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: you may not be aware of this but there is a difference in php between **!=** and **!==**, I recommend you read this carefully: [PHP Comparison Operators](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)